# Redirect a page in PartialViewResult() method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I am trying to redirect a page when certain condition is not page using PartialViewResult method . But i am unable to do it. My code is like as follow :

```
public PartialViewResult Visit()
{    
    int visit = 0;
    if (base.IsLoggedIn() == true)
    {
        visit++;
    }
    else
    {
        // toDO redirect to home/index page
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all of your code paths return a result. What should happen when a user is logged in?

Comment: Don't understand what is being asked..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code snippet you provided will not compile.  You must return a result from all code paths.  Try something like this:

```
public ActionResult Visit()
{
    int visit = 0;

    if (base.IsLoggedIn() == true)
    {
        visit++;
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ACTION_NAME_GOES_HERE");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I believe I now understand what you're trying to accomplish.  In the event an ajax request is made by a user who is not logged in, you would like the browser to redirect the user.  I suggest modifying your action method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Visit()
{
    int visit = 0;

    if (base.IsLoggedIn())
    {
        visit++;
        // whatever else needs to be done
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        // Note that this could be done using the Authorize ActionFilter, using
        // an overriden Authorize ActionFilter, or by overriding OnAuthorize().
        if (!base.IsLoggedIn())
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have configured  in your web.config, the response will be a 302 Redirect which is not what you want in this scenario.  See Phil Haack's blog post which explains how this ASP.NET behavior can be prevented and a 401 Unauthorized response can be returned:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx

Then, assuming you're using jQuery to issue the AJAX request, you can handle the 401 response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your_controller/visit',
    type: 'GET',
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            // data = your partialview
        },
        401: function (data) {
            location.href = '/the_path/to_redirect/to';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but in my senerio i can't use ActionResult

Comment: I'm curious ... Why are not able use ActionResult in your scenario?

Comment: well i am calling this method as a user control   via ajax request

Comment: thanks friend can you little bit elobrate where i will grt this error code and how?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actualy i dont understood what 200, 400 is and you get this value.

Comment: 200 and 401 are the HTTP Status Codes.  200 (OK) is the status code for a request that has succeeded.  401 Unauthorized is the status code for a request that requires authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand the issue but this might help someone as it worked for me.

```
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This works for my scenario.  Curious, if anyone else reads this, is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a partial view, you should probably look into using [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) or similar, as this kind of common logic does not belong in a view/controller. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public sealed class RecordLoggedInCountAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            visit++;
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate any controller / action you want to record this for with `[RecordLoggedInCount]`

Answer (score -2):

```
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index.aspx");
}
```

Comment: i cant use RedirectToAction or ActionResult for this senerio. I have to redirect this by using PartialViewResult only. But i didnot gety idea how to do it?